# ternary operator in ansible

Tags: ansible, conditional-operator

i have a task to create volumes with type [rw, dp,values]

i have parameter called type which has 3 values [ rw,dp,values].

using ternary operator type: "{{ (item|int < 11)|ternary('rw', 'dp') }}"

int<11----i was creating 20 volumes so i gave int<11 which created 10 volumes rw and 10 volumes dp.

above logic works for 2 values rw and dp.

how do i use 3 values in ternary operator. i want creating 21 volumes with 7 volumes type"rw" ,

7 volumes "dp" and 7 volumes "value".

"{{ (item| int< 7 )|ternary('rw', 'dp', 'value') }}" ----->this is not working as per my requirement.

Comment: "this is not working as per my requirement." => this is actually not working as [per documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#id8).  Your template expression will actually return `'rw'` when `item` exists and is less than 7, `'dp'` when item exists and is not less than seven, and `'value'` when `item` is null. Moreover, there is nothing anywhere testing the case when `item | int >= 7 and item | int < 14`.

Comment: I tried this logic  to check item | int >= 7 and item | int < 14 ...still not working

Answer (score 0):

You can work it out with jinja2 templating, I am not really sure how is the item you're iterating on is structured, this should work:

```
  - set_fact:
      volume_mapping: |
        {%- set mapping = [] -%}
        {%- set volumes = range(0,22) -%}
        {%- for volume in volumes -%}
        {%- set volume_type = {0<=volume|int<8: "rw", 7<volume|int<15: "dp", 14<volume|int<=21: "values"} -%}
        {{ mapping.append({"volume": volume, "type": volume_type[True]}) }}
        {%- endfor -%}
        {{ mapping }}
```

volume_mapping:

```
[
    {
        "type": "rw",
        "volume": 0
    },
    {
        "type": "rw",
        "volume": 1
    },
    {
        "type": "rw",
        "volume": 2
    },
    {
        "type": "rw",
        "volume": 3
    },
    {
        "type": "rw",
        "volume": 4
    },
    {
        "type": "rw",
        "volume": 5
    },
    {
        "type": "rw",
        "volume": 6
    },
    {
        "type": "rw",
        "volume": 7
    },
    {
        "type": "dp",
        "volume": 8
    },
    {
        "type": "dp",
        "volume": 9
    },
    {
        "type": "dp",
        "volume": 10
    },
    {
        "type": "dp",
        "volume": 11
    },
    {
        "type": "dp",
        "volume": 12
    },
    {
        "type": "dp",
        "volume": 13
    },
    {
        "type": "dp",
        "volume": 14
    },
    {
        "type": "values",
        "volume": 15
    },
    {
        "type": "values",
        "volume": 16
    },
    {
        "type": "values",
        "volume": 17
    },
    {
        "type": "values",
        "volume": 18
    },
    {
        "type": "values",
        "volume": 19
    },
    {
        "type": "values",
        "volume": 20
    },
    {
        "type": "values",
        "volume": 21
    }
]
```

You can append any value to `mapping` and then use it with `with_items`:

```
"{{ item['type'] }}"
```